# What is Kazari Uiharu's esper ability?

Tags: a-certain-scientific-railgun

Uihara mentioned that her esper ability is really weak, and additionally in the Railgun anime, when asked about her headband made of flowers, she asks "What headband?".

Is her ability to grow those flowers? Or is it the ability to use computers really well or something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Uiharu's ability is that she can keep the things that she touches at a constant temperature.

She reveals this to Haruue in episode 22 of the first season. (at roughly 7:30 including OP)
She also reveals that she has never told anyone else what her power is.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: It was only a few seconds out of a long series. Very easy to forget after a few years.

Comment: Now that would make for some serious CPU cooling.